# How can I ignore a row from a table if one of it's associated table's column fail to meet the condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to do the following in ruby on rails, but even if I can get an answer in mysql that would be great.

I have tables Student and Courses. Student -> Courses is one-to-many relationship.

```
  Student                   Course
|--------------|   |--------------------------------------| 
|id| name      |   |id | course_name | grade | student_id | 
|----------    |   |--------------------------------------| 
|S1| student 1 |   |C1 | Course1     | A     | S1         |
|S2| student 2 |   |C2 | Course2     | C     | S1         |
|----------    |   |C3 | Course1     | A     | S2         |
                   |C4 | Course2     | B     | S2         |
                   |--------------------------------------|
```

```
select * from Student 
where id NOT IN (select student_id from Course where grade = 'C')
```

I want to achieve same result using single SQL JOIN statement or using activerecord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Student s 
LEFT JOIN Course c ON s.id=c.student_id AND c.grade = 'C' 
WHERE c.student_id IS NULL;
```

Or join to your subquery

```
SELECT * FROM Student s 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT student_id FROM Course WHERE grade = 'C') c
WHERE c.student_id IS NULL;
```

Or use exists

```
SELECT * FROM Student s 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Course WHERE grade = 'C' AND student_id=s.id);
```

I'm afraid I can't test this at the moment and I have a suspicion that these queries may not help you. I have no experience with ActiveRecord. Let me know in the comments.

Comment: First SQL Statement worked. I am not able to understand why you used 'IS NULL' in where condition. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @chetu: A LEFT JOIN ensures that ALL rows from the left-hand table (Student) are represented in the results, even if there is no corresponding row in the right-hand table (Course). The right-hand columns - in the absence of any 'real' data - are NULL. In this query, they are the students we want... those not represented in the Course table when filtered on grade = 'C'.

Answer (score 0):

oracle:

```
select distinct s.*  from student s left join course c on c.student_id=s.id where c.grade!='c'
```

```
Student.all(:select=>"distinct student.*",:joins=>"left join course on course.student_id=student.id",:conditions=>"course.grade!='c'")
```